# Unable to hide admob banner programatically in iOS

Tags: ios, admob

I seem to be unable to hide an Admob banner during my game, using the following method to show;

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
    bannerView_.delegate=self;
    bannerView_.adUnitID = ADMOB_ID;
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [viewController.view addSubview:bannerView_];
    GADRequest *request =[GADRequest request];
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

When trying to hide it, even to test it I have hooked it up to a button

```
- (void)removeBanner{

    NSLog(@"should be removing banner");
    [bannerView_ setHidden:YES];
    [bannerView_ removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I have tried both of the above options inside removeBanner, however none of them make the banner disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to check

1. Do you call the first function more than once?  Put an assert that `bannerView_` is not already set.  If it were called more than once, you'd only be removing the last one.
2. Is `bannerView_` somehow `nil` in `removeBanner`?

edit: probably you should set `bannerView_` to `nil` after you remove it (but I doubt that would matter). Also, you could call `setNeedsDisplay` on `viewController.view` (and then `displayIfNeeded` to force it to happen immediately)

Comment: Hi Lou, it is definitely not called more than once, how would I check 2) ?

Comment: Put a breakpoint and then look in the debugger. (e.g. at the (lldb) prompt, type `po bannerView_`)

Comment: Hi Lou, appears it was being called in another class file, my mistake, thank you for your help!